# Meaning of “Attrition of Excess”

Tags: meaning

I have been reading The World of Yesterday by Stefan Zweig, and I have been having a little bit trouble understanding “... attrition of excess.” in the following sentences:

> For in the midst of his military and political victories, that was Hitler's most diabolical triumph — one man succeeded in deadening every idea of what is just and right by the constant attrition of excess.

[image]

Can somebody elaborate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the original:

> Denn das ist Hitlers diabolischster Triumph inmitten seiner militärischen und politischen Siege diesem einen Manne ist es gelungen, durch fortwährende Übersteigerung jeden Rechtsbegriff abzustumpfen.

The phrase in question is *fortwährende Übersteigerung*, which means constant (fortwährende) exaggeration or or excess (Übersteigerung). *Steigerung* means increase, so *Übersteigerung* would be "over-increase," or excess.

The phrase "attrition of excess" does not imply that the excessiveness is subject to attrition (i.e., the word "of" does not indicate possession). It means that attrition (the wearing down of people's resistance, or just general exhaustion) was caused by Hitler's constant excesses. The translator (Anthea Bell) seems to have added the word *attrition.*

An earlier translator (not sure who it was; the introduction is by Harry Zohn) renders it thus:

> For amidst his military and political victories Hitler’s most diabolic triumph was that he succeeded through progressive excesses in blunting every sense of law and order.

Comment: I prefer the latter version.  "Attrition of excess" is powerful but confusing.